# What is the correct way to update UI after action dispatched. React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Looking for a best practice for updating UI after data changed.

For example: I'm trying add post and when he has been added i need it shown on same page. Without reloading page.

Is that correct way if i'll call `action` in body of another `action` ?

For example: On Success post added -> call action which fetch all posts

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.success) { call action }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice AFAIK for what I understand you are asking would be to use something like React-thunk, so you can have async actions.

> A thunk is a function that wraps an expression to delay its evaluation.

with that you can avoid componentWillReceiveProps, pass down all your state through props to the dumb components from a controller component connected to the store.

[more info here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)